# How do I insert a newline every N characters in output log using node.js for linux terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, split

I have a javascript file that inputs info from all over, but it's very hard to read as its thousands of characters on one line.

EDIT: sorry, not output.log, but fs.appendFile

```
fs.appendFile('file', content(), function (err) ...
```

where content() is the function output;

END EDIT:

I would like it condensed into the appropriate readers view of 80 characters per line. Is there a way I can regex the output log in node.js on the terminal?

CODE:

where content() is the output of the function and the data that is saved to file.

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.appendFile('file', content(), function (err) {
   if (err) return console.log(err);
   console.log('EVENT RECORDED');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can use `.{80}` which matches every 80 characters and replace it with `$&\n` to make after every 80 characters a new line.

```js
const regex = /.{80}/g;
// a text with 240 characters (3 * 80)
const str = `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`;

const result = str.replace(regex, `$&\n`);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: sorry, I should have elaborated better. I export using ((fs.appendFile('file', err()),)

Comment: so when I open the file, it is just one long string. I tried the above, but I don't think I did it right.

Comment: I think the above code should work, try to share your code maybe I can help you.

Comment: it blocks the export of fs, and it only exports aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa... I'll share the code above.

Comment: @oryzo Save the return value of `content()` in a variable. `const str = content();` Then use `.replace()`. `const result = str.replace(...);` and lastly use `result` in your `.appendFile()` call. `fs.appendFile("file", result, ...);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const outputString = `
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim. Et ultrices neque ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis. Penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo. Viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum. Vitae et leo duis ut diam quam. Egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna. Dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at. Posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent. Nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt. Ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum. Pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor. Enim tortor at auctor urna nunc id cursus. Nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras. Turpis egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra pharetra. Orci a scelerisque purus semper eget.

Eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna etiam. Ultrices in iaculis nunc sed. Pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse. Quis lectus nulla at volutpat. Commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. Felis bibendum ut tristique et. Sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam quam nulla. Diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque.

Tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim. Platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras. Sed elementum tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium quam. Dictum sit amet justo donec. Aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum. Sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget. Dolor morbi non arcu risus quis. Amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu risus. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc sed.
`;

const formattedOutput = outputString
  .split('')
  .reduce((acc, cur, ind) => {
    if (ind % 80 === 0) {
      acc += '\n';
    }

    return acc += cur;
  }, '');

console.log(formattedOutput);
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find anything that worked for my situation as the results weren't being cut by any regex or slice that I found. It never threw any errors either.

In the end. I just created a crontab that performed this function every time it ping as saved as it only takes a few milliseconds to perform on over 500k characters:

```
perl -p -e 's/(.{44})/$1\n/g' < log > newlog
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.